# jQuery .animation() function runs line twice and not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to work on a function to scroll my page to the top side of the page when I click on an anchor. My jQuery script looks like:

```
$("a#drop-user-box").click(function()
                           {
  console.log("foor"); //Would return foo value once
  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow", function()
  {
    //console.log("foor"); Would return foo value twice?

    // Code doesn't work when in here
    // $(".drop-down").toggleClass('hidden');
    // $(".drop-down input[type='e-mail']:first-of-type").focus();
  });
  // Code does work when in here
  // $(".drop-down").toggleClass('hidden');
  // $(".drop-down input[type='e-mail']:first-of-type").focus();
});
```

What is the difference with executing the piece of code outside of the `animate()` function and within it? And why does the code not work when the two lines for the drop-down are within the `.animate()` function? Please explain me how this works.

Thanks in advance,

**Edit:**

How would I make this work?:

```js
$("a#drop-user-box").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow", function() {
        $('.drop-down').show();
    });
});
```

```css
.user-box .drop-down
{
  padding: 15px 25.5px;
 display: block;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.user-box .drop-down form
{
 width: 250px;
}

.space
{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drop-down hidden">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="e-mail" class="form-control text-box single-line" name="E-mail" placeholder="E-mail adres">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control text-box single-line" name="Wachtwoord" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Bewaar login informatie
      </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="inloggen">
  </form>
  <a href="#">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a>
</div>

<div class="space">

</div>

<a href="#" id="drop-user-box">Foo</a>
```

Comment: If your anchor has a `href`, wouldn't it redirect you somewhere else ?

Comment: The callback function is called after the animation is over. When u write inside it then it will be applied as soon as scrolltop goes to 0. When u apply outside of it then it will be applied before the animation completes.

Comment: @adeneo It directs to a hashtag sign, so to the page itself. Anyhow, how would I be able to make it work like the first case then?

Comment: If you have `<a href="#"...` it still reloads the page, generally before the animations are done

Comment: Okay suppose I added `return false;` within the `.click()` function. Why does it still not show my dropdown box? If you'd be requiring more code I can see what I can do to add it to the question.

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/40uv4z0r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it's not working is because the .show() function doesn't remove the "hidden" class name. The [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) & [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide) functions operate on the style="display:block" and style="display:none" attributes & properties. So you'll have to change this line of HTML:

```
<div class="drop-down hidden">
```

To this:

```
<div class="drop-down" style="display:none">
```

Then it will work. See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/066xaoef/) for the demo.

Comment: Is it not possible with just the usage of classes/id's instead of using the `style` property?

Comment: You can also use the hidden class with .addClass("hidden") and .removeClass("hidden") Simply replace the .show() & .hide() functions with those 2 class changing functions.

Comment: Could you show it in your fiddle as example please? I tried that but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Ah I see, I forgot to change the class before trying the change. Thanks. Could you tell me if it is possible to add an animation to showing the div aswell? Like popping up from its left top corner to bottom right corner? If you don't know what I'm talking about, let me know and I try to explain it in more detail what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You may have to pin the form to the upper right corner, with its values set to height = 0px & width = 0px. Then those two values can be increased to their full height & width values inside of the .animate() function. Try using position:absolute; top:0; and right:0; for the pinning. Then play with the animation timing & pixel values to create the animation effect that you'd like to see.